# Is it possible to write nested conditional statements in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I'm still struggling to learn the syntax of Haskell, since it's unlike any other programming language that I've seen before. In most imperative programming languages, it's possible to create nested conditional statements like this:

```
function thing1(x){
    if(x > 2){
       if(x < 5){
           return 3;
       }
       else if(x < 10){
           return 10;
       }
       else if(x >= 10){
           return 6;
       }
    }
    else{
        return 4;
    }

}
```

However, I still haven't figured out the equivalent syntax in Haskell, after several attempts: I tried creating an equivalent function in Haskell, and I got a syntax error: `prog.hs:10:1: parse error on input main'`:

```
thing1 x =
    if x > 2 then
        if x < 5 then
            3
        else if x < 10 then
            10
        else if(x >= 10)
            6
    else
        4

main = do
    putStr(show(thing1 6))
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax here: is it even possible to create nested conditional statements in Haskell, as in other languages?

Comment: The error is not related to if/else here, but to the indentation of `main`. It has to start in the same column as `thing1`.

Comment: What is the result if x >= 10?

Comment: @chirlu Then it would return `4`, if the program was formatted correctly.

Comment: @AndersonGreen No, it wouldn't. Certainly not in any popular language-with-braces. In JS that would be `undefined`.

Comment: @rkhayrov It turns out that you're right about this. I changed the code example to something valid, since my original example seemed illogical.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gZXP/

Comment: a small unrelated tip -- `putStrLn . show` has an alias, `print`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a couple of people suggested, you can do this more easily with pattern guards:

```
thing1 x
  | x <=  2 = 4
  | x <   5 = 3
  | x <  10 = 10
  | x >= 10 = ???

main = putStr (show (thing1 6))
```

Isn't that so much neater? Isn't it so much easier to figure out exactly what is returned in each case?

**Update:** Before I forget, a common idiom is to do this:

```
thing1 x
  | x <=  2   = 4
  | x <   5   = 3
  | x <  10   = 10
  | otherwise = 6
```

This makes it clearer to the casual observer that all cases are actually covered.

Comment: Yes - you need to define what the answer is supposed to be for that case.

Comment: I think you've found a good workaround for my question (which might be better than my original approach), but it still doesn't exactly answer it. Is it possible to use nested conditional statements for the same purpose, as long as every series of statements ends in `else`?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Sure, you can use a long nested if/then/else if you prefer. (Just so long as every `if` has exactly one `then` and exactly one `else`, of course...)

Answer (score 3):

You've forgot `then` after `if(x >= 10)` and you also need an `else` branch. But since `if(x >= 10)` already is the `else` branch of `if x < 10` you could just remove `if(x >= 10)` or make it into a comment:

```
thing1 x =
if x > 2 then
    if x < 5 then
        3
    else if x < 10 then
        10
    else
        6
else
    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have an incomplete (un-answered) branch in the X > 2 section?

```
 if x < 5 then
    3
 else if x < 10 then
    10
 // else, what answer here?
```

The `else` in Haskell is mandatory.

See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures

Comment: In that case, I would want to break out of the current conditional block and move on to the next `else` statement. Is it possible to do this in Haskell?

Comment: Use guards. It is better anyway.

Comment: I think you're meant to write well-valued expressions, not GOTO and BREAK statements, in Haskell! If it's not an expression it's not gonna fly. You're not imperative here.

Comment: @ThomasW Does this mean that it's basically impossible to write nested conditional statements in Haskell (with the same structure as in JavaScript, Java, etc.)?

Comment: @AndersonGreen think about what this means in a functional language. Everything is an expression.  Every expression has to return something.  What does (if x then y) return, if x isn't true?  Try visualizing your if/else structure as a series of nested expressions and you'll see where the conceptual problem is.

Comment: No, it just means that each one of them has to be "complete" -- and have a value for all cases. What kind of well-formed expression doesn't have a value (even NaN) for some cases?

Comment: Your expression could be ProgramState, unchanged from the previous State -- or a Maybe. These are ways of returning an answer that "does nothing". _"No answer" is, very obviously, not possible._

Comment: @ThomasW Then is it possible to write nested conditional statements in Haskell, as long as every series of conditional statements ends in `else`? This appears to solve my problem.

Comment: @AndersonGreen `if <expression> then <expression> else <expression>` is an expression, in Haskell. It can appear anywhere an expression can appear, including in one of the sub-expressions of an if/then/else. There is no such thing as a "series of conditional statements", each and every `if` has exactly one `then` part and exactly one `else`, and whether it happens to be nested inside part of another if/then/else is completely irrelevant.